# How to get IPA(international pronunciation alphabet) by Google Cloud Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, ipa

I'm trying to develop a system to get IPA(international pronunciation alphabet) from speech files by Google Cloud Service. However, I have no clue how to realize the system. Do you have some idea to realize the translation system with Google Cloud?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/phonemes

Comment: I checked this but I think this is for text to speech thing.

Comment: Hi @uekyo, Can you clarify more on your use case? Which cloud service has to give IPA from speech files? Is it speech to text?

Comment: Currently IPA is only available with text to speech. If you want the feature of using IPA along with speech to text, you can open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your requirement.

Comment: @uekyo Try IBM TTS API, it will return IPA as well

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Speech-to-Text will convert your speech files to text. From there, it depends on the language. For English you have a choice of sending each word to the Oxford English Dictionary or IBM Watson Text-to-Speech. Either will return an IPA transcription. The OED does only English lemmas but will return two or three pronunciations of some words. IBM will return lemmas and declensions for Dutch, English, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, and Spanish, but only a single pronunciation for each word.

I would not attempt to convert English to IPA programmatically. Spanish, on the other hand, has only five vowels and fifteen rules for pronouncing consonants. I wrote a Spanish-to-IPA converter in a day or two.

If you need non-Roman languages such as Arabic Google Translate has a romanization service in beta preview. Writing a converter to IPA shouldn't be too hard.